# Convert a no. from string to integer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to integer in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858978/convert-string-to-integer-in-c)

Convert a no. from string to integer.

Eg: str:"1234"
convert to int a=1234;

i want the hint with proper explaination

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858978/convert-string-to-integer-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique that this task is probably trying to get at is accessing each of the digits, e.g., `str[0] - '0' = 1` and multiply by their place values.  But atoi is much faster!

Comment: My rationale is that this is, IMO, likely a student problem.

Comment: can you explain ur first answer part with example

Comment: Your string is 4 digits, so the first place value is 10 ^ 3.  The first character is '1', so to get its value, subtract '0' = 1.  1*10^3 = 1000.  Repeat for the other places and sum them all up.

Answer (score 4):

use `atoi()`:

```
int foo = atoi(str.c_str());
```

Comment: i want answer without using inbuilt function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this properly and test for errors in conversion, I recommend the use of [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm). Here is an example of usage:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast>

std::string num_string("1234");

try
{
  int num=boost::lexical_cast<int>(numString);
}
catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast &ex)
{
  // Handle failed conversions
}
```

If for whatever reason you cannot use boost in your project, at least use a standard `stringstream` to do the conversion, in order to get some semblance of error checking.

Comment: AFAIR lexical_cast was very expensive. Agree with the use of stringstream though

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged it C++ you could have a look at [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/):

```
bool convertStr(const char *str, unsigned int *num) {
  istringstream iss(str);
  return (iss >> *num);    
}
```

Or you could even use templates:

```
template <class T>
bool fromString(T &t, const string &s, 
                ios_base& (*f)(ios_base&) = dec) {
  istringstream iss(s);
  return !(iss >> f >> t).fail();
}
```